# Linear compile-time algorithm to convert variadic template into function calls

Tags: templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments.  I need to turn those arguments into a sequence of function calls where the order matters.  The following approach works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

void printType(const std::type_info& ti) {
    printf("%s\n", ti.name());
}

void expandVariadic() {
}

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void expandVariadic(const First& first, const Rest&... rest) {
    printType(typeid(First));
    expandVariadic(rest...);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    expandVariadic(10, "hi", std::cout, std::vector<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

However, the above code expands to a quadratic number of arguments passed to expandVariadic.  I can force-inline expandVariadic, but that still means quadratic compile time.

Is there a linear-time approach to effect the above?

(They need to be function calls: imagine a logger that generates a sequence of output calls, or something that fills a vector<> with type information.)

Comment: I don’t see how the above code results in a “quadratic number of arguments passed,” is it possible to explain briefly?

Answer (score 4):

```
struct sink{template<class T>sink(T&&){};};
void run_in_order(){}
template<typename... Fs>
void run_in_order(Fs&&...fs){
  sink _[]={((void)std::forward<Fs>(fs)(),0)...};
  sink{_};// warning elimination
}
```

use:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void expandVariadic(const Ts&... ts) {
  run_in_order([&]{printType(typeid(ts));}...);
}
```

which nicely hides the magic inside `run_in_order`.  `run_in_order` takes a sequence of lambdas or other nullary callable objects and invokes them in order from left to right.  This works because evaluation within the `{}` of the `sink _[]` line is guaranteed by the C++11 standard to be from left-to-right.

I cast the return value to `void` then invoke the comma operator with a `0` on the RHS to guarantee that we get a value that can be converted to a `sink`.  The `(void)` cast deals with the corner case that the lambda passed in returns an object that overrides `operator,`.

The downside to this technique is that support for packs inside lambdas is less broad than support for other pack expansions.  A number of compilers I have poked at have been able to do parameter pack expansion of most code, but failed when the parameter packs in question are inside a lambda, and the expansion is outside.

Comment: Isn't it possible to add an additional element to the `_` array instead of an overload? `sink _[] = {0, ((void)forward<Fs>(fs)(),0)...};`

Comment: `tyepname Fs` should be `typename... Fs`, and `sink(_)` should be `sink{_}` to prevent it from being parsed as a new declaration of `_` as type `sink`. And left-to-right evaluation of initialisers in `{ ... }` is not implemented yet at least in GCC, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @hvd was not aware of that gcc bug.  My next attempt would be to divide and conqor the arguments, which gives n lg n compile complexity instead of n^2.  A nice thing about `run_in_order` is at least those details are hidden inside it, instead of at each use site.  Oh and I should replace `(void)blah,0` with `sink{blah}`

Comment: Experimenting a bit: you can avoid the lambda [by using `std::bind`](http://ideone.com/Wh6RIR), where it shows that in this specific case, GCC does use the right order of evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

It exists a frequently seen trick to expand a parameter pack without recursion while calling any function : [here it is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef669083c6a80fd2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

void printType( const std::type_info& ti ) {
    std::cout << ti.name() << '\n';
}

// because cast to void is a non generic way to hide unused variable warning.
template <typename T> void ignore(T&&) {}

template<typename... Ts>
void expandVariadic(Ts&&... ts) {
    // expand by using a initializer list.
    auto il { ( printType( typeid(std::forward<Ts>(ts)) ), 0)... };
    ignore(il);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    expandVariadic(10, "hi", std::cout, std::vector<int>());
    return 0;
}
```